# Counting files with FOR (command batch)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I want count only files in a directory with Windows batch.
(The ultimate purpose is to call a vbs file if I have any files whatsoever.)

Here's what I have so far:

```
set /a db=0
echo %db%

for /f %%i in ('dir /b') do (
    set /a db=%db%+1
    echo %db%
)

echo %db%
```

This will me give the following: 0 0 0 0 1 for the value of %db%
(as I have 3 files in the directory right now)

Maybe trivial, but why won't it increase the value of %db% during the loop, only in the end?

What happens between the last loop of for (where %db% still was 0) and the last line (where %db% is 1 already)?

How should I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the batch file is being executed, each line or block of lines (lines enclosed in parenthesis) is first parsed and then executed. During the parse phase, variable read operations (where you retrieve the value of the variable, that is `%var%`) is removed, being replaced with the value inside the variable. Once this is done, the resulting command is executed.

Inside your `for` loop you are changing the `db` variable, but you can not retrieve the changed value. All the read operations were replaced with the value in the variable before the `for` command start to execute.

The usual way to solve this problem is to enable delayed expansion and change the `%var%` syntax into `!var!` syntax where needed. This tells the batch parser that the variable/value substitution must be delayed until the command is executed, not when the line/block is parsed.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a db=0
echo %db%

for /f %%i in ('dir /b') do (
    set /a db=!db!+1
    echo !db!
)

echo %db%
```

Now the read operations inside the `for` loop are using delayed expansion.

But, you don't even need it. The `set /a` uses its own parser that is able to retrieve the value in the referenced variables, so you can use any of those options

```
set /a db=db+1
set /a db+=1
```

to change the variable without having to use read syntax.

Also, unless you need to take into consideration hidden files, it is better to not use a `for /f` processing the output of a `dir` command that is executed in a separate `cmd` instance. Just use a `for` loop

```
set /a "db=0"
for %%a in (*) do set /a "db+=1"
echo %db%
```

But, if as you point all you need is to know if you have any file, and not the number of them, all this is not even needed

```
dir /a-d >nul 2>nul && ( echo there are files ) || ( echo there is not any file )
```

It just executes the `dir` command, with folders excluded (`/a-d`), discarding any output (`>nul`) or error message (`2>nul`). 
 - If any file is found (no errors), the command after the conditional operator `&&` is executed. 
 - If there is not any file, the `dir` command fails and the command after the `||` conditional operator is executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to detect whether or not there are any files, [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476) already showed a reliable way in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717578).

To count the number of files you can let the [`find` command](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) do the work, as it features a `/C` switch that counts the number of matching lines. If you specify to do an inverse search by `/V` (so to return all non-matching lines), together with an empty search string `""`, all lines are returned.
So when the input for `find` comes from a `dir` command line that lists all files, the total count of files is returned (`2> nul` suppresses the error message in case no files are present):

```cmd
2> nul dir /B /A:-D | find /C /V ""
```

To capture the count in a variable, use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

```cmd
for /F %%C in ('
    2^> nul dir /B /A:-D ^| find /C /V ""
') do set "COUNT=%%C"
echo %COUNT%
```

Note that special characters like `>` and `|` need to be escaped by preceding with `^` in order for them not to be processed immediately but in the `cmd` instance initiated by `for /F`.